# Aligning an image to the edge of a table cell

Tags: css, image, css-tables

I'm in the process of heavily customising one of those pre-made forums, and one of the things I am trying to do is to replace the online/offline graphics with something else, and reposition them, so that instead of being positioned at the end of the user name, it is positioned in the left corner of that part of a post.

My intention was to get the img code within div tags assigned with a style of `float:left`, and `position:absolute` (need to use absolute, otherwise the other elements, such as the user name and avatar will become off-centered). Currently, this is what I have:

http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/6357/18555863.gif

As you can see, there appears to be some sort of padding or margin that I have been unable to get past. I have tried adding a style to the div for `margin:0px, padding:0px`, `left:0px`, and `top:0px`, but none of them have been able to move the image into the right place (that is, to close that gap between the edges of the image, and the border of the table cell).

Answer (score 0):

You could try assigning the image with a negative margin.

```
img{
margin-left: -10px;
margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid the image disappeared completely when I applied that.

Comment: Oh wait, I applied that to the div, not the image. Still, with it in the right place, there is no change. The image is still stuck in the same place it was.

Comment: Try setting the images margin-top: and margin-left: to negative values rather than just top: and left:

Comment: Could you paste the css of the img and the div it is in please

Comment: It's alright. I asked somewhere else as well, and I got it to work. Turns out that I was on the right track, but while the div I had for the image was supposed to be absolute, as I had done, I needed to set the positioning of the image itself to relative, so that I could get the top and left values to work.